# How to take Email Address in Html in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some Html Like as :

```
<div class="user">
<span>Email</span>
<span>John_1990@gmail.com</span>
</div>
```

How can I Parse this Html and featch just Email Address?
thanks

Comment: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ is the most known HTML Parser. Have you tried anything?

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: @SonerGönül Can you Explain or post a Example ?

Comment: @DanielA.White I'm Beginner programmer . can u post an Example?

Comment: the best thing you can do as a beginner (or any level) programmer is try to figure it out yourself before asking for help

Comment: Have you tried to use jQuery?

Comment: @rochasdv I am familiar with jquery but i do not how can do this

Comment: @Jonesy You're right. But I do not know what should I search field

Comment: @job1393 you need to use HtmlAgilityPack like I show you in my answer.

Comment: put a ID on <span> tag and get with a selector, something like this=> var email = $('#spanId').html();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use HTML Agility Pack.You can add reference like this.

```
Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack
```

Here is little example, how you can do it. First you are reading the HTML and take all the lines with span tag. After that you are checking the InnerText if it is email address, for this you will use regex.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string html = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A!!</td>
        <td>te2</td>
        <td>2!!</td>
        <td>te43</td>
        <td></td>
        <td> !!</td>
        <td>.!!</td>
        <td>te53</td>
        <td>te2</td>
        <td>texx</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div class=""user"">
<span>Email</span>
<span>John_1990@gmail.com</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>";

            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);

            List<HtmlNode> spanNodes = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "span").ToList();

            List<string> emailAdd = new List<string>();
            foreach(HtmlNode node in spanNodes)
            {
                if (Regex.IsMatch(node.InnerText, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$"))
                {
                    emailAdd.Add(node.InnerText);
                }
            }

            foreach(string email in emailAdd)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(email);
            }

        }
```